# Локализация python на могучий русский язык

Tags: python, python-3.x

Может кто знает как исправить ошибки ? Очень интересно )

```
From dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class цел:
   число: int = 0

переменная1: цел

фун = def # ошибка
класс = class # ошибка
если = if # ошибка
лябда = lambda # ошибка
импорт = import # ошибка
иначе = else # ошибка

def вывод (выводимое):
    print(выводимое)

вывод (переменная1)
```

Comment: Т.е. как #define?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138596/python-define-equivalent

Comment: Victor VosMottor - да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Не рекомендую

Но... Можно отредактировать [исходный код](https://github.com/python). [Вам вроде конкретно сюда](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Parser). Возможно, еще где-то надо будет редактировать, я не изучал source code. XD

Как вариант.

Answer (score 3):

### Почему локализация Python на русский язык это плохая идея?

Python создан на английском, и он будет иметь кучу багов с русским языком.
Вы видели какой-то язык программирования с русским синтаксисом который популярен?
Зачем делать локализацию, чем она вам поможет?
Зачем так усложнять, если вы сами используете англ. слова только написали их на русском?
Тот же `import` по идее должно бить слово подключить или другие команды.
Это просто трата времени!

#### Все-ровно хотите сделать локализацию?

Если ваш ответ да, то подумайте какие проблемы будут с этим трижды.
Даже если так, то вы испортите красоту кода. Вам действительно это важно?
Насчёт переменных вроде-бы можно называть на русском но не рекомендуется
А вот функции, циклы и тд уже не получиться.
Если же уж сильно хотите то создайте программу которая будет переводить всё на англ с русского но это я считаю пустой тратой времени.
Типа своего препоцессора.

Comment: Ну почему же, если так надо, можно свой препроцессор написать, беря пример с с/с++ ;)

Comment: Если же уж сильно хотите то создайте программу которая будет переводить всё на англ с русского но это я считаю пустой тратой времени. цитируя с моего ответа

Comment: Я это и имел в виду, можно вопрос отредактировать и включить то, что это называется препоцессор.  ;)

Comment: Ну простите, я всё таки junior)

Comment: Я без наезда, просто порекомендовал изменить, т.к. это не компилятор ;)

Comment: @Victor VosMottor изменил.

Comment: Ок.....................

Comment: 1) Баги можно выловить и исправить. 2) Язык 1С имеет некоторую популярность в своей сфере. 3) Локализация это патриотично и импортозаместительно :D 4) А почему вы решили, что код на русском будет некрасивый?

Comment: @andreymal Так не принято, не делают и на надо. Это bad practice.

Comment: andreymal плюсую+

Comment: Интересно. Уже вижу как пишу свой русский пайтон код XD ага
привествие(): привет = "привет" вернуть привет

Comment: @ІванШнір XD XD XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor видимо вас уже чипировали американским чипом))

Comment: @andreymal Представьте ненавистный вам js на русском ;)

Comment: Русский питон это конечно прекрасная идея но распространение не сравнится с en версией, + многие пакеты нужно переписывать. в общем идея на 5+ а вот реализация будет на 1-...

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что def, class и все прочие штуки из вашего списка с ошибками - это не объекты, не какие-то значения. Это ключевые слова и их нельзя присваивать. Парсер языка их разбирает ещё до того, как будут выполняться какие-либо присваивания.

Comment: Может возможно отредактировать этот парсер ?) И может возможно добавить свои ключевые слова подобного типа ?

Comment: @tormozzzz Только если редактировать source code...

Comment: @Victor VosMottor - Я даже готов прочитать этот source code может вы знайте где  его найти и какой файлы отвечают за ключевые слова ?)

Comment: @tormozzzz [репа](https://github.com/python) ⇒ [вам вроде вот сюда](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Parser)

Comment: @Victor VosMottor - там они действительно есть как ключевые слова, теперь я знаю как теоретически это решить, если бы вы ответили так же в ответе я мог выбрать вас как решение проблемы(в комментарии не могу :( )

Comment: @tormozzzz О сейчас напишу, раз вопрос не закрыт. XD